# Is there anything preventing me from working many consecutive days?

Tags: united-states, hours, new-york

I work in a manufacturing facility in New York state. I am an hourly employee, but I'm in a supervisory position. After working a full week, I came in all day Saturday and a half day Sunday before starting another week, and will most likely have to work this coming Saturday, making 13 consecutive days.

Are there any laws that prevent this, or would otherwise affect my pay rate aside from the normal "time and a half" overtime?

Comment: Are you a hourly worker?

Answer (score 8):

> Are there any laws that prevent this, or would otherwise affect my pay
>   rate aside from the normal "time and a half" overtime?

There are no laws in New York that would prevent you from working 13 days in a row if you so choose.

If you would rather not work 13 days in a row, NY State labor laws require that you be given 24 continuous hours off within every 7 days of work if you are not a white collar worker. If that isn't happening and you want to pursue it, contact the New York State Department of Labor to file a complaint. The fact that you are a supervisor may matter, but I'm not sure that it does.

If you are in a union, you should be talking with your rep.

The usual overtime laws would apply, but nothing out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 4):

I am not a lawyer but, New York has a [1 day in 7](https://labor.ny.gov/formsdocs/wp/LS611.pdf) regulation, but it merely states that the employer cannot *require* you to work for 7 days in 1 week (must be allowed 24 consecutive hours of "rest" per 7 day week).

If you voluntarily work more than 7 consecutive days, I don't think the regulation applies. However, YMMV, and you may want to consult with labor relations or a lawyer if you feel you are being taken advantage of.